# If ignores my == sign

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to make a game (simple 2d platformer).

The program runs as it should, but an if statement doesn't work correctly.

I have this function:

```
    int Collision::platformCollision(SDL_Rect *hitbox, SDL_Rect plat) {
    if (checkCollision(*hitbox, plat)) {
        //X
        //LEFT SIDE
        if (hitbox->x + hitbox->w > plat.x && hitbox->x + hitbox->w < plat.x + 5) {
            hitbox->x = plat.x - hitbox->w;
            return 1;
        }
        //RIGHT SIDE
        if (hitbox->x < plat.x + plat.w && hitbox->x > plat.x + plat.w - 5) {
            hitbox->x = plat.x + plat.w;
            return 2;
        }
        //Y
        //UPPER SIDE
        if (hitbox->y + hitbox->h > plat.y && hitbox->y + hitbox->h < plat.y + 10) {
            hitbox->y = plat.y - hitbox->h;
            return 3;
        }
        //BOTTOM SIDE
        if (hitbox->y < plat.y + plat.h && hitbox->y > plat.y + plat.h - 10) {
            hitbox->y = plat.y + plat.h;
            return 4;
        }

    }
    //NOT COLLIDING
    return -1;
}
```

So I have this function return an `int` whenever it collides with a certain part of the platform.

Then I have this function:

```
    void Player::playerCheckPlatCollision(SDL_Rect rect) {
    if (platformCollision(p_hitboxPTR, rect) == 3) {
        setGravityF(0.0);
    }

    if (platformCollision(p_hitboxPTR, rect) == 4) {
        p_space = false;
    }
    return;
}
```

The problem should be easy to fix.
When I debug the program it gets to `return 4;` in the `platformCollision` function, but when I do

```
if (platformCollision(p_hitboxPTR, rect) == 4) {
        p_space = false;
}
```

It doesn't put `p_space` as `false`, it just ignores the `== 4` and when I debugged, I saw it got to that if statement.

Can someone please help.
Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't look like an SSCCE

Comment: Instead of calling `platformCollision` multiple times with the same variables, call it just once and store the returned value in a variable that you check in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

If platformCollision returns 4 on the first call, it alters state, and will not return 4 on the second call.

```
void Player::playerCheckPlatCollision(SDL_Rect rect) {
    int bang = platformCollision(p_hitboxPTR, rect);
    if (bang == 3) {
        setGravityF(0.0);
    } else if (bang == 4) {
        p_space = false;
    }
}
```